# Average by season using R

Tags: r, average

I have daily data by location (latitude and longitude) and i want to average by season. I want to consider Jan-March as season 1, April to June season 2, July to September season 3 and October to December season 4. Here is example data and output needed.

```
Lat            Long           Date          Value.
30.497478    -87.880258      01/01/2016       10
30.497478    -87.880258      02/02/2016       15
30.497478    -87.880258      02/05/2016       20
33.284928    -85.803608      01/02/2016       10
33.284928    -85.803608      01/03/2016       15
33.284928    -85.803608      01/05/2016       20
```

Output should be

```
Lat              Long         Season      Avg Value
30.497478      -87.880258       1            15
```

Would also like to add Median and SD in addition to mean. I have seen some examples using library zoo and dplyr but haven't been able to work it for this case. Hopefully someone here can help. Thanks.

Comment: Please wrap your code in code tags `{}` button and do let us know then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
df <- read.table(text = "
                 Lat            Long           Date          Value.
30.497478    -87.880258      01/01/2016       10
                 30.497478    -87.880258      02/02/2016       15
                 30.497478    -87.880258      02/05/2016       20
                 33.284928    -85.803608      01/02/2016       10
                 33.284928    -85.803608      01/03/2016       15
                 33.284928    -85.803608      01/05/2016       20", header = T)


df$Season <- cut(as.numeric(substr(df$Date, 4, 5)), c(1,4,7,10,12), c(1,2,3,4), include.lowest = T)

library(dplyr)
options(pillar.sigfig = 6) # to prevent Lat and Long to be rounded

df %>% 
  group_by(Lat, Long, Season) %>% 
  select(-Date) %>% # since all other variables all grouping vars, just deselect Date
  summarise_all(funs(mean, median, sd))

     Lat     Long Season    mean  median        sd
    <dbl>    <dbl> <fct>    <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>
1 30.4975 -87.8803 1      12.5000 12.5000   3.53553
2 30.4975 -87.8803 2      20.0000 20.0000 NaN      
3 33.2849 -85.8036 1      12.5000 12.5000   3.53553
4 33.2849 -85.8036 2      20.0000 20.0000 NaN
```

Note that for Season 2 no sd can be given, since there is only one Value for each combination of Lat & Long in the sample data.

Comment: Thanks for this response. the dates are in mm/dd/yyyy format. So all above where season 1. How would you split then?

Comment: Just do substr(X, 1, 2) then instead of substr(X,4,5)

Comment: Thanks i tried doing substr( X, 1, 2) and i got warnming message NAs introduced by coercion. Some had the season number in the new column and some just had NA.Also it was reading october as season 3.

Comment: part of the problem may be Jan to September is 1 to 9 and not 01 to 09. so hence its only cutting october (incorrectly should be season 4 and not 3) to december. any advice?

Comment: i formatted the date to show 0 for months 1-9 and i modified your code from c(1,4,7,10,12) to c(1,3,6,9,12) and it worked perfectly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi len, if i want to make dec-Feb as 1, and mar-may as 2, june-aug 3 and sept to nov 4 - what would be the formula. I have been messing around but can't seem to get it to work. any thoughts?